# JavaFX set BarChart xAxis/width to size

Tags: java, javafx

I want to force the X size of my BarChart but can't.  Is there a way to implement this? Maybe by overwriting a function in BarChart?

```
import com.milkyway.trader.missionControl.OptionHistorySingleton;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SetBarChartBarSizeExample extends Application {

    VBox root = new VBox();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

        BarChart<String, Number> chart = new BarChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);
        chart.setLegendVisible(false);
        root.getChildren().add(chart);


        chart.setBarGap(5);
        chart.setCategoryGap(0);

        // Doesn't work.
        //xAxis.maxWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty());
        xAxis.setMaxWidth(20);
        chart.setMaxWidth(20);



        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        XYChart.Data barA = new XYChart.Data("A", 100);
        XYChart.Data barB = new XYChart.Data("B", -100);
        series1.getData().addAll(barA, barB);

        chart.getData().addAll(series1);


        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setHeight(600);
        primaryStage.setWidth(400);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the max width you're setting here is smaller than the min width, so what you observe is the min width. `chart.setMaxWidth(20)` is certainly having an effect, though. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve that's not happening, though. Can you clarify?

Comment: @James_D It does have an effect, the chart will not scale past some width, but that width is not 20px. It seems like BarChart is internally overriding 20px.

Comment: Try setting the min width of the chart to 0.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the *minimum* width of a chart is a value computed from the number of bars, the minimum width required to display each bar, the minimum width required to display the y-axis, and other settings such as the padding and margin. The minimum width of your chart is greater than 20, so when you set the maximum width to 20, there is a conflict between the minimum and maximum width (both of these constraints cannot be met at the same time). The chart chooses to respect the minimum width over the maximum width in this circumstance, so you see the width of the chart at the minimum that its computed width will allow.

You can allow any maximum width to be respected by setting the minimum width to zero. In the following change to your code, you will get a chart of width 20 (but be aware that this is not enough space to display the bars, so all you will see is the y-axis):

```
 @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

    BarChart<String, Number> chart = new BarChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);
    chart.setLegendVisible(false);
    root.getChildren().add(chart);


    chart.setBarGap(5);
    chart.setCategoryGap(0);

    chart.setMinWidth(0);
    chart.setMaxWidth(20);



    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    XYChart.Data barA = new XYChart.Data("A", 100);
    XYChart.Data barB = new XYChart.Data("B", -100);
    series1.getData().addAll(barA, barB);

    chart.getData().addAll(series1);


    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setHeight(600);
    primaryStage.setWidth(400);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

If you just want the chart to resize with the window, the `VBox` will do that by default, so you only need to set the minimum width to zero for that to happen:

```
    chart.setMinWidth(0);
    // chart.setMaxWidth(20);
```